# asp.net 4.5 MVC SQL select like

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

So I have this code:

```
 public ActionResult SearchIndex(string id)
    {
        string searchString = id;


        var members = from m in db.Members
                      select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            members = members.Where(m => m.town.Equals(searchString));
        }

        return View(members);
    }
```

This selects all the town names in my database and I've got it to display in a drop down menu.

How can I change this so that when it's displaying the town names, it will only show each town name once.

For example, if I have 3 londons in the database it will show all 3 londons in the drop down menu. I want it to only show 1 london

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [`Distinct` method on IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var towns = members.Where(m => m.town.Equals(searchString))
                  .Select(m => m.town).Distinct();
```

This will `Select` only the town value, then get the `Distinct` values, so London will only come up once.

Comment: @user1300788 Sorry, thats because you are trying to overwrite the members variable with something that isnt the same type.  Create a new variable called towns (which is more meaningful anyway) and set that.

Comment: I still get the same error :/ Can you edit your answer to show how you do this?

Comment: I feel really silly but I posted the wrong bit of my code to where the distinct would go. `@foreach (var item in Model) { 
     string mytown = item.town.*enter distinct here*
  <option value="@mytown"> @mytown</option> ` 
how would I fit distinct into this?

Comment: It would be something like `@foreach (var item in Model.Select(m => m.Town).Distinct()) ...`  Then you would just use item, instead of mytown.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that the accepted answer addresses your original question, which was to return an enumerable of `Member` from a Controller to a View, with an optional filter on town, restricting the list to a maximum of one member in each town:

```
var members = db.Members; // Or .AsQueryable();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    // Apply the conditional filter, returning Members
    members = members.Where(m => m.town == searchString);
}

// First of each member only (randomly)
return View(members
             .GroupBy(m => m.town)
             .Select(grp => grp.First()));
```

It seems however that your real requirement is to

- View with filtered `IEnumerable<Member>` as the @Model
- As a secondary requirement, populate a dropdown with distinct towns

In this case, you can also project an `IEnumerable<string>`, e.g. into `ViewBag`, or better, create a custom `ViewModel` class containing both the filtered list of Member and the distinct towns for the drop down.

```
ViewBag.DistinctTowns = db.Members.Select(m => m.town).Distinct();
```

Comment: How can I add an orderBy alphabetical to this bit`(m => m.town).Distinct();` ? Code works great btw thanks

Comment: @user1300788 .Distinct().OrderBy(t => t);  (and +1 StuartLC)